# Why is my op-amp giving same output for low voltages?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac, esp32, non-inverting

So I am trying to make analog output 0-10vdc with my esp32 microcontroller.
I have read that esp can give true analog voltage cause it has DAC so my plan is to connect one of esp32 DAC pins to non inverting op-amp circuit to get a gain of 3 so I have 0-10VDC analog output from the op-amp. I have connected everything according to online schematics for non inverting op-amp (using lm741cn), My R1 is 1k fixed resistor and R2 is trimmer 2k that I put on the value of 2k so it gives me 3 gain in theory. In the esp32 code I change dac value from 0-255 and it actually gives 0-3.15vdc on the output of esp32 pin. Problem is that for low values of dac (0-127 tested) I get same output on op-amp of 6.68Vdc instead of proper linear voltage that I should get (0-5VDC in theory). Can someone tell me what could be the problem here? I tested connections and everything should work fine.

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram to your post.

Comment: Note that lm741 is not rail to rail. Should be ok only if supplied with +15V and -15 V.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp)

Answer (score 3):

An LM741 is not the best choice here. You're outside the input range of the op-amp and the output cannot swing to even a bit near the negative rail.

You can either give the op-amp a negative supply (-10V to -12V, for example), as well as a positive supply of 12V or so,  or replace it with something like an LM358 dual, with a supply of +12 and GND.

Comment: The LM741 isn't even rated for anything less than 20V (+/-10V) supply voltage.

Comment: @JonathanS. True. Minimum recommended PS voltage is +/-10V, answer edited accordingly.